# Datagrid SelectedIndex in wpf mvvm set to 0 on RaisePropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm developing a project in c# Wpf with mvvm light.

In this project I have a datagrid with SelectedIndex bound to an int in the ViewModel.

DocumentViewModel:

```
private int _docSelectedIndex;
    public int DocSelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _docSelectedIndex; }
        set
        {

            _docSelectedIndex = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DocSelectedIndex");

        }
    }
```

The View:

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="Column"
                  x:Name="docgrid" 
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                  DataContext ="{Binding Document, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DocItems}"
                  SelectedIndex="{Binding DocSelectedIndex,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
             ...
             ...
</DataGrid>
```

The binding works! but whenever I want to update the Grid with new data I need to RaisePropertyChanged("DocItems").

This seems to change the selectedindex to 0. I've tried to set the selectedindex back to the original, but the index is always set to 0 in the end.

This is the method that calls RaisePropertyChanged:

```
public void UpdateDocumentList(object sender, TypedEventArg<DocListUpdatedEvent> e) 
    {
        var temp = new List<SFODocument>(e.Value.DocumentList);
        var meta = _meta.GetPageMetaData();

        foreach (var d in temp)
        {
            foreach (int i in d.PageList) 
            {
                meta[i].docid = d.DocumentID;
                _meta.UpdateExistingMeta(meta[i]);
            }

        }
        _docItems = new ObservableCollection<SFODocument>(temp);
        RaisePropertyChanged("DocItems");
    }
```

How can I update the datagrid and still keep the original selectedIndex ?

Comment: Since the ItemsSource is bound by docItems property, all Items are kind of "refreshed", it is, like the name says it, an item-"source-change". So for the wpf, there's understandable reason to throw away a selection index from the old source. In your case, after the ItemsSource change, there may be some new, some old entries to the user, and you want to keep the index of visually old entries ? If that's the case, I would do this: keep the selected object as viewmodel property, compare its contents after the source change with each new item. If it's found, set selectionindex, of not, leave zero.

Comment: I'm not really interested in the Item itself, but I want to keep the row selected, even after RaisePropertyChanged. You mention that I should set the selected index after sourcechange, and that is what I'm trying to, but the index is set to 0 no matter what I do.

Comment: This sounds that the index (which is bound 2-way i guess) is overwritten to zero at the pont the new collection is bound to the itemssource. So make sure that it gets not overwritten. You could easily set a flag for preventing this in your viewmodel, just before RaisePropertyChanged("DocItems");

Comment: I've tried flagging with a bool _isRaisingProperty. But the value is set to 0 after the flag is set to false again.

Comment: to escape of this binding issue, why not create a 2nd viewmodel property "initialupdateIndex" that's bound oneway to source to SelectionIndex. This surely won't be reset to zero

Comment: Oops.. actually it is "OneWay", not "OneWayToSource".

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the selectedindex back to the original this way

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => docgrid.SelectedIndex = oldIndex), DispatcherPriority.DataBind);
```

If it won't work try to use another priorities.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I tried every priority, but it still ends up setting it to 0 in the end.

Comment: After you have called UpdateDocumentList(), docGrid.SelectedIndex = oldIndex may work ok! (No BeginInvoke() needed) Make sure that your oldIndex viewmodel property is not overwritten (to zero) at the point the ItemsSource changes! This is important to check with the debugger.

Comment: I've checked with the debugger, and I can see that the oldindex is correct, and it is setting the selected index(which at this point still is the same). But after this is set, another call is made with the value = 0.

Comment: Where are another call from in stack?

Comment: ...just find the correct place in code, that goes along with the wpf update process (see my comment above :-)

Comment: Neptunao: The call is raised from external code (WPF - RaiseProperty). As for the flagging solution, It happens after flag is unset.